# How can I run a normality test on count data in the following table?

Tags: r

My data is formatted in R as follows:

```
        Group Light Dark
1  Dermaptera    29   29
2   Oniscidea    72   54
3     Diptera    54   39
4 Lepidoptera    17    7
5  Formicidae    14    6
6   Hemiptera     3    9
7   Diplopoda     8   17
```

I am certain that this data is not normally distributed as it is count data, and histograms show that it is clearly non-normal, for example using `hist (dataframe$Light)`. When I try to input `shapiro.test (dataframe)`, I get the error code `is.numeric(x) is not TRUE`, and when I try to instead input `shapiro.test (dataframe$Light)` or `shapiro.test (dataframe$Light + dataframe$Dark`, the p-value shows the result to be of normal distribution.

How should I instead format this data when putting it into R so that I can test for normality and subsequently test for statistically significant relationships?

Comment: can you provide `dput(x)`  of your data?

Comment: `> dput(light_dark)
structure(list(Group = c("Dermaptera", "Oniscidea", "Diptera", 
"Lepidoptera", "Formicidae", "Hemiptera", "Diplopoda"), Light = c(29L, 
72L, 54L, 17L, 14L, 3L, 8L), Dark = c(29L, 54L, 39L, 7L, 6L, 
9L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stats)
```

Provided your data sits here:

```
dd <- data.frame(Group = LETTERS[1:10], Light = sample(1:10), Dark = sample(1:10))
```

Shapiro test p-value for each specified column:

```
pvalues <- dd %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Light, Dark), funs(shapiro.test(.)$p.value))
```

You can even find Shapiro test p-value groupwise:

```
pvalues_by_group <- dd %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Light, Dark), funs(shapiro.test(.)$p.value))
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, the p-value for each specified column works from your code but I am still sure that the p-values I'm getting are wrong as they show a normal distribution. Does providing `str` of my data frame give you any info on why this is happening? ``> str (light_dark)
'data.frame': 7 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Group: chr  "Dermaptera" "Oniscidea" "Diptera" "Lepidoptera" ...
 $ Light: int  29 72 54 17 14 3 8
 $ Dark : int  29 54 39 7 6 9 17``

Comment: `dput(your_data_object_here)` .Also, please specify, what you want to achieve. Find p-values or something else.

Comment: `> dput(light_dark) structure(list(Group = c("Dermaptera", "Oniscidea", "Diptera",  "Lepidoptera", "Formicidae", "Hemiptera", "Diplopoda"), Light = c(29L,  72L, 54L, 17L, 14L, 3L, 8L), Dark = c(29L, 54L, 39L, 7L, 6L,  9L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))`
I want to determine normality with p-values as you did with your code, but I am sure that the p-values I am getting back are incorrect. When I look at the data for each column in a histogram I can see that the data is not distributed normally. Once I know the normality, I then want to carry out a chi squared or a t test.

Comment: You don't need to use Shapiro test or any normality test on such small data sample. You could assume in advance that data do not follow normal distribution and proceed with non-parametric tests.